# best way to automate updates installs

Tags: select, automation, batch-file, field

I wanted to know if there was a way to have an app automate to answer the questions.. 
I have created a batch file that starts the app in the start up folder.

so I have 2 problems, one was deleting the batch file once it ran from that folder
2. answering the questions for the app?

Is that even feasible?

we don't have SMS which I was used to in my previous job so batch update automation comes in handy as a sencondary method.

Comment: What kind of questions are we talking about? Is the app asking questions? The batch file? I'm a little confused here.

Answer (score 1):

If under "answering the questions for the app" you meant some GUI input, like typing text and pressing buttons, you need to look for a simple tool like AutoIt. It's free.